# Deleted the /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport folder and now I can't test on my device

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios-simulator, developer-tools

I deleted the /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport folder by mistake trying to fix an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error.  The folder I was supposed to delete was: `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148)/Symbols` and of course Xcode didn't ask to collect symbols again. Xcode doesn't recognize my device any more, so I can't test on my device.

How can I restore the folder?

Comment: Reinstall the iPhone SDK and it should return.

Answer (score 2):

Download the same version of xCode/Developer Tools again, install it to /Developer-new or anything except /Developer.  Then in Terminal run:

```
sudo cp -rv /Developer-new/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport
```